# Html email verification

Tags: php, html, email

I have researched how to get my email verification working again. Because one minute it was and  then the next it wasn't. 
this is the line of code :

```
pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]*[@]\ul.ie"  required
```

It was working and its not anymore. Anyone knows why?
I can't put all of it because it wont let me.

Comment: i think this can help you http://emailregex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you must use regex for email validation? Try to use PHP filter_var function for email validation:

```
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
   $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
}
```